# Issue with Android Hybid app to display remote image with Ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to Ionic.
I am using Ionic Framework (1.3.20), Angular JS, Cordova 5.0.0

**Template file** browse.html code:

```
<div class="col-50"><img ng-src="{{availableImages[currentImage].src}}" /></div>
```

**app.js** code:

```
.state('app.browse', {
    url: "/browse",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/browse.html",
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

**controller.js** code

```
.controller('Ctrl',function($scope) {
      $scope.currentImage = 0;
      $scope.availableImages = [
        {
          src: "http://lorempixel.com/160/160/people/3"
        }
        ];
      console.log("reading image in controller !!!");
})
```

**Header details**:

```
Request URL:http://lorempixel.com/160/160/people/3
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found (from cache)
Response Headers
Client-Via:shouldInterceptRequest
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; XT1033 Build/LXB22.46-28; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/42.0.2311.129 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

**Config.xml** file:

```
  <access origin="*"/>
```

**Error** on console:

```
GET http://lorempixel.com/160/160/people/3 404 (Not Found)
```

I verified the url http://lorempixel.com/160/160/people/3 is showing image in my mobile browser. but the image is not coming on the app.

Comment: This is weird. I just tried it on Codepen.io and it worked. Does your application have the permissions for internet?

Comment: yes added these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Okay. Try installing this plugin - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist and add `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />` to your **config.xml**.

Comment: `(from cache)`... have you tried clearing your app cache?

Comment: @Keval, Now one more, on console log getting "No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin." how to add this?

Comment: thanks I found it in the doc of the plugin added  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">

Comment: Glad to know it worked.

Comment: I can access remote images, but my API calls are not returning any data. Why?

Answer (score 47):

Whitelisting the domains using [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) solves the issue.

Add the plugin via CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and then add the following line of code to your app's **config.xml**:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

and

this `meta` tag in your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

**EDIT:** The reason for this issue:

From Cordova 4.0.0 for Android's update:

> Whitelist functionality is revamped
>
> - You will need to add the new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to continue using a whitelist
> - Setting a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported and is the recommended way to whitelist (see details in plugin readme)
> - Network requests are blocked by default without the plugin, so install this plugin even to allow all requests, and even if you are
>     using CSP.
> - This new whitelist is enhanced to be more secure and configurable, but the Legacy whitelist behaviour is still available via a separate
>     plugin (not recommended).
>
> Note: while not strictly part of this release, the latest default app
>   created by cordova-cli will include this plugin by default.

Comment: Amazing!! My question is...What in the BGZUZ is going on with Cordova??? Why does it require this all of a sudden? Been working with ionic for over 6 months now and this pops up

Comment: Did you update your project's libraries? I've edited my answer with the reason.

Comment: Yeah I did, but if I didn't come across your post, I most likely would have torn my hair out by now. It does make sense however. But just poorly advised to the community.

Comment: better do `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` so you get a released version rather than the latest github code

Comment: This works for me except for on my `release.apk` which is obviously a real issue! Already have my app in the App Store with this issue :(

Comment: You mean the app works fine when you're debugging, but when you build with `release` parameter, it doesn't?

Comment: I banged my head cause I thought it has something to do with cors, great answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Build this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/GprtU3r8NDgYwO6jGRkp?p=preview

My html file:

```
<div><img ng-src="{{ availableImages[currentImage].src }}" /></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.currentImage = 0;
$scope.availableImages = [{
  src: "http://lorempixel.com/160/160/people/3"
}];
```

It seems that everything is alright...
Tested with angularjs 1.3.15

Comment: Yes this is weird, wamp, plnkr, Codepen shows that image is coming up, but when I am loading the apk in my andorid mobile using "ionic run" its giving 404 for the image.