# Android app built with ionic cannot access phone's internet

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I created an android app with ionic framework, the app gets data from external API using ajax, and loads header logo from same external API. Its working fine on my browser once I disabled web security (chrome). But once I deployed to my android phone, The app was unable to access/use internet. The data is returning empty page and the logo is not found .
I have set :
1.  in config.xml
2.  in manifest before application

Please what am I doing wrong or missing.

Thanks

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29916802/4412363. Also, you might face `CORS` issue. In that case, you can use `$http.jsonp` in your Ionic+Angular app.

Comment: The whitelist worked. Thanks a million times