# Cordova / Ionic : $http request not processing while emulating or running on device

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build, ionic-framework

Everything were going well last week and while i was running the application on device or emulating with Genymotion, all the calls to the api were working (Either returning the data or failing but at least showing something).

I was using

```
ionic run android
```

I add to update the global cordova ionic:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Since that all the $http requests are not even processing. I can't get any responses while the Api is still working fine and the CORS are perfectly set.

The only way i found is to use the option --livereload or -l :

```
ionic run -l android
```

I want to avoid using the livereload at any cost.

I started to create a project from scratch using ionic 1.0.0 and cordova lib 4.3.0.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http) {

  alert('calling api');
  // Create an anonymous access_token
  $http
      .get(domain+'/oauth/v2/token?client_id='+public_id+'&client_secret='+secret+'&grant_type=client_credentials')
      .then(function(response){
          alert(response.data.access_token);
      });
})
```

So while using :

```
ionic serve
```

It is correctly alerting 'calling api' then the response (An OAuth access token for that example).

But while using :

```
ionic run android
```

It is only alerting 'calling api' but doesn't seem to process the http request.

Did anyone experience something similar? I'm getting big headaches on that.

Comment: See if this answer helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29916802/4412363

Comment: Thank you i'll try that now and get back to you.

Comment: Okay that is working! Well is you want to write an answer linking to this post i'll be glad to validate it.

Comment: It actually is a duplicate, but your question is more specific in nature, which will lead people to it when they search on this issue, so I will add the answer as `Community Wiki`.

Comment: Yea this is why it was pretty hard to find the answer with the keywords i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: For me with cordova 6.3.0, I have to modify `<meta>` of .html file that make a network request. As follow, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`. I add `*` after `'self'` then it works.

Or better to be specific, but I have to specifically specify protocol too i.e. `https://yourdomain.com` and replace that `*`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With the update of Cordova 4.0.0, you will face an issue of not being able to make HTTP calls to RESTful APIs and load external resources, which include other HTMLs/video/audio/images.

Whitelisting the domains using [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) solves the issue.

remove whitelist plugin if already installed:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Add the whitelist plugin via CLI:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and then add the following line of code to your app's **config.xml** which is located in your application's root directory:

**Reccomended** in the documentation:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />
```

or:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

and

this `meta` tag in your `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>
```

The reason for this issue:

From Cordova 4.0.0 for Android's update:

> Whitelist functionality is revamped
>
> - You will need to add the new cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin to continue using a whitelist
> - Setting a Content-Security-Policy (CSP) is now supported and is the recommended way to whitelist (see details in plugin readme)
> - Network requests are blocked by default without the plugin, so install this plugin even to allow all requests, and even if you are
>   using CSP.
> - This new whitelist is enhanced to be more secure and configurable, but the Legacy whitelist behaviour is still available via a separate
>   plugin (not recommended).
>
> Note: while not strictly part of this release, the latest default app
> created by cordova-cli will include this plugin by default.

Comment: isn't this opening up the security a bit too much?  why do I have to enable `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-evals` ?

Comment: I have modified my answer - we can also add `<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />`, which was recommended in the documentation.

Comment: remove cordova-plugin-whitelist and add back the whitelist solved my problems without any code change... and the whitelist is the same version..... omg....

Comment: none of the above worked for me, then I found out the issue is with http apis (https apis are working), any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58384888/http-returns-null-data-status-1-only-on-android-when-sending-http-requests

Comment: Doesn't seems to be working anymore on the Android SDK 30. Does somebody have the same issue & had an answer to it ?

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me, when I tried the following…

In Config.xml, allow access & navigations to your domains:

```
<access origin="http://yourdomain1.com" />
<allow-navigation href="http://yourdomain1.com"/>
```

Then in index.html, add the Content-Security-Policy as below:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://yourdomain1.com  data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';  media-src *;  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with ionic app. In my case, the android app was running fine on my mobile but it was not making the http calls on other team members mobile.

After debugging the device using chrome://inspect#devices. I came to know the exact error.
During the HTTP call, the app was giving ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED error.

I used below link to allow sending the data in clear text format in AndroidManifest.xml file in my playpen.
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/err-cleartext-not-permitted-in-debug-app-on-android/164101

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending http request to a non https url, Then Make sure you have added

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For alternative options check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/2995027)

Answer (score 0):

This is a network security related issue. To fix this, replace resource/android/xml/network_security_config.xml

With,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>api.mydomain.in</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```