# $http get in ionic not working on real device even cordova-plugin-whitelist is installed

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am creating an ionic app that fetch json value from remote server using $http get. It displays the data when I run it on the browser but not on real Android device. I also have `cordova-plugin-whitelist` installed already.

Here is my code on the `index.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

`controller.js`

```
.controller('ProductsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $http,    $stateParams) {
      console.log("ProductCtrl: prod_id = " + $stateParams.prod_id);
      $scope.host = "xxxx";
      $http.get("http://"+ $scope.host +"/xxxx/xxxx.php?cat_id=" + $stateParams.prod_id)
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.products = response.data;
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers,config){
        console.log('data error');
      })
      .then(function(result){
        things = result.data;
      });
})
```

`config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.xxxxxxx" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>XXXX</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com/">
      Your Name Here
  </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <allow-navigation href="http://xxxx.com/*" />
</widget>
```

As you can see in `index.html` I've put the `<meta>` tag as suggested on other post that I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326148/cordova-ionic-http-request-not-processing-while-emulating-or-running-on-dev)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` but nothing has changed.

`cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist`

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

These are the errors displayed on the console. Mostly are just 404 like this:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

But this one is probably because of the `<meta>` ..

```
Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
(anonymous function) @ localhost:8100/?ionicplatform=ios:98
```

Please help.. thanks in advance..

Comment: Any error r u getting ?? It will be good if u post what error u r getting

Comment: Other errors are just 404 aside from this one.

Comment: Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".

Comment: Another thing, My cordova version was 6.5.0 and I tried to downgrade it to 6.3.0. Nothing happened.

Comment: can u Please catch me at naresh.k.suruvu@gmail.com, will discuss it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer last time but I'll just post it now. I usually run my android app using Ionic Lab but when I run my app from console (`ionic run android`), I've noticed this:

> "Using this version of Cordova with older version of corodva-android
>   is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-android@5.0.0 or
>   newer. "

so I just upgraded my cordova:

```
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android@5.X.X
```

Then it worked finally.

Answer (score 0):

I use this as my meta tag and it handles all such things. Try this a let me know it it works

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src *;style-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; script-src * &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;">
```