# Ionic 1 external HTTP request

Tags: android, angularjs, http, ionic-framework

I am trying to consume HTTP services from an external location but only get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT because the request never gets to the server.

The app have been built with `ionic 1` and `angularjs`, using `angular-resource` to consume services

After reading several SO questions I end up setting up my app as follows:

**config.xml**

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />    
<access origin="*" />
```

**index.html**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://server_ip:8080 data: gap: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

of course, *service_ip* is the real server ip address and it accepts HTTP requests as I have been able to consume them using REST clients.

**Other considerations:**

- The app is built and launched using command `ionic run android`.
- I am using plugin `cordova-plugin-whitelist`. (I removed and added it again following several SO answers... without success).
- Also using plugin `angular-resource` for HTTP requests. Requests are correct as I have tested them using local machine ip and they work, **problems came after changing that ip to the server ip**.

It looks like a **CORS** problem, I expected to solve it via `meta` tag in index.html file but the behaviour is the same even when I set up:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: sorry are you testing on IOS or on ANDROID ?

Comment: try using  'cordova run android'

Comment: Try check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326148/cordova-ionic-http-request-not-processing-while-emulating-or-running-on-dev

Comment: @digit I have already tried that solution but didn't work. In fact the second meta tag is the same.

Comment: I guess it must be network issue. Check the firewall and also try ping from your phone to your computer what is the status. Also you must connect using same network if you want to test using localhost.

Comment: @digit Sorry, maybe I have explained myself wrong, I am testing the app using command "ionic run android" in my computer but the HTTP request are sent to a external server with ip "server_ip" in the question. I am able to consume those services using REST clients

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi android

Comment: Did you try if you can replicate the problem on a real device? it usually is common that CORS issues raises when you try to run any sort of http requests on a simulator, and that's why you should use a proxy instead to test these: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/cli/test.html#service-proxies

Comment: @briosheje I run the app on a real device connected via USB debugging. ionic run android -> myapp-debug.apk

Comment: @juankysmith: I'm not really sure how this could happen then, since by definition whenever you run the application on a real device you **don't** need any sort of configuration to consume any HTTP service, since CORS issues don't exists at all when you use a real device. Perhaps you may find something useful here: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ . It's strange though, maybe the problem is DNS-related? It doesn't make much sense that it's throwing a connection timeout.

Comment: Also, please check in android manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the problem was on my device. I had to upgrade Google's **WebView** application in my device to get it work.

Solution was found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionicview-app-http-request-to-external-api/18696/11)