# Ionic - HTTP Post working on serve and -l but not working when run on android device

Tags: typescript, http, ionic-framework, cors, cordova-plugins

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
});

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
this.http.post('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'+url, body, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    let response = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
    if (response.MessageCode == 'SUCCESS') {
      this.loginMessage = 'success';
      this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, response);
    }
    else {
      this.loginMessage = 'failure';
    }

   }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I'm having CORS issue. So, I used it before the URL to make it work.

Below is the config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.16" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^1.11.0" />
```

Request headers-

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 64.77.72.122
Origin: http://localhost:8100
```

Response headers-

```
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1245
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 15 Mar 2018 15:37:44 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I have tried all the options mentioned in other similar questions like the one mentioned below.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326148/cordova-ionic-http-request-not-processing-while-emulating-or-running-on-dev)

Can someone address this issue? TIA.

Comment: Can you PLEASE include a full set of request AND response headers that you're seeing, for both the preflight OPTIONS request (if any) and also the GET/POST request that you're trying to make.

Comment: Edited. Please take a look.

Comment: Nevermind. Fixed it. It had something to do with server-side and body params. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the CORS issue, I would recommend this extension for Chrome, since you will only have this kind of error while running on browser.

Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Remove all you have done to solve the CORS issue and try to run again your program.

Comment: The extension will do it for you. You just need to install it.

Comment: I tried that chrome extension. Didn't work. But appending https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ to the url worked during ionic serve and ionic run livereload. Need to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Create on your **server**, in the root of requested URL, a ".htaccess" file with this content:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a server-side body params issue.

CORS is only a problem while testing on a web browser.

It can be handled by launching the browser as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677/9321880). There is no need to use any chrome extensions or plugins to handle it.