# $http returns null data , status -1, ONLY on android when sending http requests

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have a cordova + angularjs app

It sends some request to some rest apis,

when I rum my app on browser (`cordova run browser`) everything is working, no CORS issue, no other errors

the problem is when I run on device (`cordova run android`) I am getting `null data , status -1`.

There were different solutions on SO, removing and adding `cordova-plugin-whitelist` none of them working.

I tried downgrade/upgrade cordova `8.0.0`, `9.0.0`, cordova-android `6.4.0`, `7.0.0`, `8.1.0`, still not working

Then I tried to call other rest apis on the web except my self, then I found out when calling `https` apis it's working, calling `http` not working, (even when I call the working https api via http it doesn't work)

```
//$http.get('http://192.168.0.13/JarChee/api/location') // not working
//$http.get('http://mysite-002-site1.dtempurl.com/api/location') // not working
//$http.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees') // not working
//$http.get('http://shibe.online/api/shibes?count=5&urls=true&httpsUrls=false') // not working
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') // not working
$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') // working
    .then(function (response) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(response))
    }, function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err))
    });
```

### config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

any help appreciated