# Cordova app no longer sends cookies in its httprequests

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cookies, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic (Cordova/Angular) app that I have running on an Android phone (Galaxy S6 Edge, Android 5.1.1).
This app communicates with a server for which the user must login first.

After login, authentication cookies received from the server are automatically send back to the server on each request by including withCredentials=true inside $http calls.

For instance:

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: LoginStatusUrlMobile,
                responseType: 'document',
                withCredentials: true
            })
```

This used to work, but this weekend the cookies were no longer sent and the app no longer works.
I tried several things to figure out what is going on:

- Is it the new release of Chrome 46?
  => I uninstalled the updates of Chrome and the Chrome webview on my Phone but this didn't make any difference
- In my development environment the app still works (Chrome version 46.0.2490.71 on Mac with --disable-web-security to turn of same origin policy)
- I tried to run the app inside Genymotion and this worked on a virtual device running Android 4.4.4 but it didn't send the cookies on a virtual device running Android 5.1.0
- The app also runs on iOS, and I haven't tested that thoroughly yet but it works OK on my iPad with iOS 8.1

This is my situation right now and my question is:
does anyone know how to send cookies back to the server with angular $http requests, when withCredentials=true no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by removing the Android platform and then recreating it.
After that I added the cordova-whitelist-plugin as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912773/issue-with-android-hybid-app-to-display-remote-image-with-ionic-framework).

Now everything is working properly again.