# error of shouldInterceptRequest in *.apk ( Ionic with asp.net mvc OAuth )

Tags: android, angularjs, oauth, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

I just builded an app by ionic-framework. The server side is:

> bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity

All function works fine in the PC chrome browser, authorization pass and request all get correct response.

[Request success screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePQth.png)

but once we builded the html5 and angularjs files into apk, function fails.

> ionic build android
>
> ionic run android

Got the [Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmOkv.png)  by chrome inspect plugin.

There a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912773/issue-with-android-hybid-app-to-display-remote-image-with-ionic-framework). I also tried that way but also can't work.

> Client-Via:shouldInterceptRequest

In index.html file there a cross domain js reference also failed.

I find this might relate to shouldInterceptRequest method in SystemWEbViewClient.java

I common few no use code and just direct response the result, finally the js reference successed.

but the auth request still failed

and I am not sure whether this is a best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just comment the code below which in shouldInterceptRequest method, then it all works.

```
 public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
        // Check the against the whitelist and lock out access to the WebView directory
        // Changing this will cause problems for your application
    // *********************** below four lines of code commented.-----
    //    if (!parentEngine.pluginManager.shouldAllowRequest(url)) {
    //        LOG.w(TAG, "URL blocked by whitelist: " + url);
            // Results in a 404.
    //        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
    //    }

        CordovaResourceApi resourceApi = parentEngine.resourceApi;
        Uri origUri = Uri.parse(url);
        // Allow plugins to intercept WebView requests.
        Uri remappedUri = resourceApi.remapUri(origUri);

        if (!origUri.equals(remappedUri) || needsSpecialsInAssetUrlFix(origUri) || needsKitKatContentUrlFix(origUri)) {
            CordovaResourceApi.OpenForReadResult result = resourceApi.openForRead(remappedUri, true);
            return new WebResourceResponse(result.mimeType, "UTF-8", result.inputStream);
        }
        // If we don't need to special-case the request, let the browser load it.
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!(e instanceof FileNotFoundException)) {
            LOG.e(TAG, "Error occurred while loading a file (returning a 404).", e);
        }
        // Results in a 404.
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/plain", "UTF-8", null);
    }
}
```